# Mapping Ctrl+Arrow for Home/End/PageUp/Down

Tags: windows, remapping, keymap, fn-key

I'm using Windows 7 on Dell New Inspiron 14z Ultrabook.
It doesn't have <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd>/<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd> keys. Instead I have to use <kbd>Fn</kbd> + arrow keys.

Can I re-map those to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + arrows or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + arrows or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + arrows?

That way I could go one page up and down with only my right hands rather than with the left hand on the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key and right hand on arrow key.

Also, volume up and down is assigned to <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>. Can I re-map them to <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd>? Existing functions assigned to <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> will be replaced by <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>.

Is it possible?

Comment: The accepted answer pointed me in the right direction, but its syntax is not valid - see my answer for the correct syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, but you'll need to use a third party program such as [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).
For example if you wanted to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Up up to <kbd>pg up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + down to <kbd>Pg Dn</kbd> you would write:

```
^{Up}::{PgUp}
^{Down}::{PgDown}
```

in your AHK file. See the [Remap Reference](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm).

I've come to understand that recent versions no longer recognize this, It seems page Up and down have been changed. Try this if the above does not work:

```
^Up::PgUp
^Down::PgDn
```

Make sure you run as administrator in Windows Vista/7/8

Comment: `^{Down}` is Ctrl+Down, not Fn+Down.  Typo?

Comment: No, the OP wanted to map Ctrl + down to PgDn.

Comment: Yes, but your answer said it was Fn+Down.  Jared Tritsch edited it to correct.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and comments. Can I assign (Right Ctrl + arrows) or (Right alt + arrows) but not (Left ctrl or alt + arrows)

Comment: because I think ctrl or alt + arrows might have their own function in Windows or other applications. So I leave them for LEFT ctrl or alt and use RIGHT ctrl or alt for my own hot key.

Comment: The above example doesn't work for me.  It says that "^{Up}::{PgUp}" is an invalid hotkey.  I'm using Win Vista.

Comment: Same for me on Win 7. "^{Up}::{PgUp}" is an invalid hotkey.

Comment: @JochenJung I have updated this post for more recent editions of Windows.

Answer (score 2):

The script in the accepted answered does not work (AHK rejects it as invalid), so I went to the #AHK IRC channel and they told me that it should be:

```
^Up::PgUp
^Down::PgDn
```

So, no squigly brackets, and PgDn or PageDown, but not PgDown.

Or, some people seem to need:

```
^Up::Send {PgUp}
^Down::Send {PgDn}
```

This works me for (Windows Vista, AHK 1.1.13.01)

Answer (score 1):

The AutoHotkey's documentation says (v. 1.1.28.02):

`Return` will become your best friend. **It literally STOPS code from going any further, to the lines below.** This will prevent many issues when you start having a lot of stuff in your scripts.

So the whole script should look like:

```
^Up::
    Send, {PgUp}
return
^Down::
    Send, {PgDn}
return
```

I would like to suggest also addition another two hotkeys (even if you already have Home & End buttons on your keyboard):

```
^Left::
    Send, {Home}
return
^Right::
    Send, {End}
return
```

In my opinion, it's better to use an Alt key instead of Ctrl for that purpose. Because many programs could has own implementation of Ctrl+PgUp/PgDn shortcut.