# Assign Home and End to Fn+arrows

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Is is possible to assign <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd>/<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDown</kbd> to combinations of <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>arrow keys</kbd> in Windows 8.1 (I have HP Elitebook 8540p if that matters)?

Motivation: in particular I like keyboard of my current laptop a lot, but it's time to move on - and there are quite some offers of new laptops that don't have separate Home/End buttons, which I tend to use a lot, even when typing this question. Instead, I am supposed to use Fn+arrow keys as <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDown</kbd>. Before buying such laptop, I wanted to try whether I can live with it, or whether I should only focus on laptops with these keys separate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remap key combinations in Windows](https://superuser.com/q/21752/241386)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<kbd>Fn</kbd> is not a key that generates a scan code so **no one knows about its existence** except for the keyboard controller. If you press <kbd>Fn</kbd> along with another key that has the *Fn function symbol* on it then the keyboard controller will convert that combination to the real scan code and send to the OS.

As a result if on the keyboard *<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> does have some function*, like changing brightness or volume then you can assign <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> to <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd>/<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDown</kbd> by remapping the <kbd>brightness ☀</kbd> or <kbd>volume</kbd>  keys to them. But the HP Elitebook 8540p's keyboard isn't one of them. And I believe HP never puts any *Fn* functions to the arrow keys

[image: HP Elitebook 8540p keyboard]

However it does have **<kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd>/<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDown</kbd> at the top row** like any laptops with a numpad (the red rectangle above). It also has those keys in the numpad (the green rectangle)

In fact what you said *"there are quite some offers of new laptops that don't have separate Home/End buttons"* is incorrect. **All the laptops I've ever seen have those keys**, just at different locations. Personally I despise any keyboards that require me to use 2 keys for <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd>/<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDown</kbd> because I use them extensively, so I've always tried to look for laptops with them on single separate keys. However, it's time to move on - and there are quite some good deals for laptops without those on separate keys so I tried the ones with a numpad and was quite happy with that, just turn off numlock by default and I can navigate with single key presses. I don't like to reach the keys on the top row which requires me to move my hand a lot. It's also lucky that I hate laptops smaller than 15.4", and a lot of new big laptops have a numpad

If you really just want to use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> then you're out of luck, unless those generate some hidden scan codes that doesn't show on the key label. You can use AutoHotkey or various other tools to check. See [Finding the scan code of FN Key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24423724/995714). If they don't then you have to choose another combination, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> or <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd>

There are a lot of questions about this on this site

- [Remap laptop brightness keys to Fn + Arrow keys](https://superuser.com/q/165932/241386)
- [How To Map Fn+Key (Multiple Keys) To Other Key in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/513892/241386)
- [Is it possible to create your own Fn+Key combinations on Windows 8.1?](https://superuser.com/q/928299/241386)
- [Remap "Windows key + Ctrl + Left or Right arrow" to "Fn key + Ctrl + Left or Right arrow"](https://superuser.com/q/1336395/241386)
- [Remap FN to another key](https://superuser.com/q/65/241386)
- [Mapping Ctrl+Arrow for Home/End/PageUp/Down](https://superuser.com/q/486426/241386)
- [Can I configure my windows key to act like a fn key?](https://superuser.com/q/1042896/241386)
- [How can i map Fn+[keys] to emulate multimedia keys (prev, pause, next song...) in a laptop?](https://superuser.com/q/506749/241386)

Comment: Is this answer still valid in Windows 10? I guess yes but worth checking

Comment: @Taladris it's not related to any specific Windows version, because as I said from the first sentence: the OS never knows about the existence of the Fn key. You must use workarounds or a different key

Comment: I ended up just remapping Ctrl plus Up/Down arrows instead (using AutoHotKey) - not ideal, but workable. This is what I added to the AutoHotKey script (you'll need to replace `\n` with a newline), plus the analogous ones for down (e.g. `send +{end}`).

`; On Ctrl + Up, send home \n ^up:: \n send {home} \n return \n ; On Ctrl + Shift + Up, send home & highlight text \n +^up:: \n send +{home} \n return`

Comment: Can't add newlines to comments, but for my previous comment, [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/1394392/new-keyboard-pressing-fn-key-left-right-arrows-key-doesnt-skip-to-the-begin/1613486#1613486) has a more readable version.

Comment: It's hard to upvote an answer that tells me what I don't want to hear. But—here—take it before I change my mind

Comment: On my Asus laptop, Fn+left/right are media control keys, so the following AutoHotKey 2.0 script worked (with `\n` replaced with a newline): `Media_Prev::Home \n Media_Next::End`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the fn key on laptops is not reported as a keystroke - rather the keyboard has specific keys which you can use with the fn key to produce a different keycode. I discovered this by checking what was reported when the key was pressed, which was nothing, as opposed to other modifier keys like Alt or Shift which have a scancode of their own.

In summary: No, it's not possible because the fn key isn't a key in its own right and is only valid in combination with the specific keys (as printed usually in blue on the keytop for those specific keys).

Hope this helps!